# resistance in a dc circuit

Tags: electrical-resistance

Herein is my question. On my gm vehicle, I replaced the dash gauges with aftermarket gauges.  So, I replaced the battery light with a volt meter. I have burned up several alternators.. Have been told that by removing battery light, I also removed the resistance from the circuit going to the alternator and thereby causing the alternator to fail.  Question,, how much resistance do I need to put in the circuit to make the circuit operational and not ruin the alternator?
The vehicle is a 95 S10 with the CS130 AC Delco alternator. Will resistance also drop the voltage?
I really need some help here and greatly appreciate the help that you can give me. I am really dumb when it comes to this circuitry.
Thank you very much.

Comment: You should ask on a car forum.

Comment: Would http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/ be a better home for this question?

Comment: Woe is he who messes with electronics before understanding the design of the original system.